# Diminutive words stemming / lemmatization

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch, nlp, morphological-analysis

Currently I use 'lucene' and 'elasticsearch', and have next problem.
I need get stemmed form or lemma for [diminutive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) word. For instance :

- *doggy -> dog*
- *kitty -> cat*

etc.

But I get next results :

- *doggy -> doggi*
- *kitty -> kitti*

Is there any way (not important ready to use library, any algorithm, approach etc.) to get root / original word form for [diminutive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) word forms?

Target language : Russian.
For example :

- *собачка -> собака*
- *кошечка -> кошка*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of chain have you used for English stemming? I would be surprised you got this by using `PorterStemFilter`.

Comment: You cannot (and should not) get *cat* from *kitty* using stemming or lemmatization: "cat" is neither the lemma nor the stem of "kitty".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, as a side note: What you're trying to do isn't typically called stemming or lemmatiziation.

Your first issue would be mapping the token observed (e.g. *собачка*) to its normalised form (e.g. *собака*)-- Naively, this could be done by creating a [`SynonymFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) which uses a [`SynonymMap`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymMap.html) mapping dimunitive forms to their canonical forms. However, you'll likely run into problems with any natural language because not all derivations are unambiguous: For example, in German, *Mädel* ('girl'/'lass') could be a diminutive form of *Magd* (an archaic word meaning 'young woman'/'maid') or of *Made* ('maggot').

One way of disambiguating these two forms would be to calculate the probability of each canonical form appearing in the given context (e.g. the history of the preceding *n* tokens) and then replacing the dimunitive form with the most probable canonical form (using a custom-made `TokenFilter` to do so)-- See e.g. [the Wikipedia entry for word-sense disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-sense_disambiguation) for different approaches.